# Why are the verb singular and the pronoun plural in 1 Corinthians 4:6?

Tags: 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 4:

> 6 I have applied all these things to myself and Apollos for your benefit, brothers, that you may learn by us not to go beyond **what is written**, that none of you may be puffed up in favor of one against another.

what
ἃ (ha)
Personal / Relative Pronoun - Accusative Neuter **Plural**
Strong's 3739: Who, which, what, that.

is written.
γέγραπται (gegraptai)
Verb - Perfect Indicative Middle or Passive - 3rd Person **Singular**
Strong's 1125: A primary verb; to 'grave', especially to write; figuratively, to describe.

Why are the verb singular and the pronoun plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple and uncomplicated.  Let me provide an explanatory translation of the clause in question buried in 1 Cor 4:6.  (See 2 Peter 1:21)

> ... so that you may learn not to go beyond the things (pl) of what
> was written [by the Holy Spirit - singular] ...

The at is, the two words in Greek have different references and thus do not have to agree in number.  Specifically:

- ἃ refers to the things (plural) that were in the Bible Scriptures
- γέγραπται is the verb with a singular implied subject, viz, the Holy Spirit (as per 2 Peter 1:21), ie, that have been written by the Holy Spirit in the Scriptures

Thus, the number of each word is quite correct.

Comment: +1 @Dottard I'd like to copy your answer here over to my subreddit :)

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That neuter plural subjects normally take a singular noun is part of the grammar I learned in Greek class.  But, here is the section from Dr. Wallace's grammar that explains the full details.

> A.      Neuter Plural Subject with Singular Verb

> Although there is a lack of concord in such constructions, they are not infrequent. Indeed, a neuter plural subject normally takes a singular verb. It is an example of constructio ad sensum (construction according to sense, rather than according to strict grammatical concord). Since the neuter usually refers to impersonal things (including animals), the singular verb regards the plural subject as a collective whole. It is appropriate to translate the subject as a plural as well as the verb, rather than translate both as singulars.
> --
> Wallace, D. B. (1996). Greek Grammar beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament (p. 399). Zondervan.

Comment: I'd like to copy your answer here over to my subreddit :)

Comment: You mainly need to reference Dr. Wallace.

Comment: OK, thanks, my friend :)